# What's the best way to select data from multiple tables in androids sqlite

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I'm trying out some new stuff with sqlite on android.

According to a book I'm reading selects from tables will be done like the following

```
String criteria = "name = 'Smith' AND prename = 'John'";  
String[] columns = new String[]{ "id", "name", "prename"};  
Cursor c = db.query("person", columns, criteria, null, null, null, null);
```

My Question is now how's the best practice way to select data from multiple table like in other databases i would just use a query with joins. is there a way to do the same with sqlite or do i need to help my otherwise?

Thx for your help

Comment: you obviously did not read any reference documentation for SQLite or you would know you could use a JOIN clause. Read the answer to the question in the comment above. Also look Here https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: You can write reqular SQL like in other databases with the`db.rawQuery()` function. See the `SQLiteDatabase` documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need rawQuery method.

Example:

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

Use ? bindings instead of putting values into raw sql query.